# stickyheader is not working in p-datatable in angular

Tags: html, css, angular

I have implemented p-datatable in angular13 as below but sticky header is not working there.please suggest

```
             <p-dataTable
               #datatable
                editable="true"
               [globalFilter]="versionFilter"
               [immutable]="false"
               [value]="datasource"
               [(selection)]="selectedRows"
               [resizableColumns]="false"
               [responsive]="true"
               [rows]="10"
               [paginator]="true"
               [scrollable]="true"
               [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]"
               [sortOrder]="-1"
               [stickyHeader]="true"
               
               
             >
               <p-column
                 [sortable]="true"
                 [style]="{ width: '129px' }"
                 header="Version"
                 filterPlaceholder="Search"
                 field="versionNo"
                 [filter]="true"
                 filterMatchMode="contains"
               >
```

removed scrollable and tried other fixes but no luck

Comment: I hope this can help you https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/11099

Comment: still unable to find the solution